# How do I get nginx to escape % signs in page address

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am running a website using django with nginx as my database. In my development environment any addresses that contain a "%" sign automatically get escaped as %25 and work fine (running sqlite3 in development) but in production the % sign is not escaped and causes a "400 bad request"

the address format is domain.com/{pk}/{title that contains %}

django is then using the pk to get the item from the database.

Comment: It is rather strange that a URL contains a `%` in the first place, since the URL encoding attaches special semantics to a `%`. So it looks more to me that there is a problem with constructing the URLs in the first place.

Comment: the {title that conatins %} section comes from the database and is a hyphenated style charfield

Comment: then it looks to me that you do not pass it through a "url encoder", this will typically escape characters.

Comment: i think its happened somewhere between dumping the development environment database and then loading it in production. I will just write a quick script to encode the %

Comment: please don't encode just the `%`. Other characters like `?` and `&` are encoded as well, by encoding only `%`, things will actually get worse (since then the string is "partially encoded", and it is then harder to fix the damage). Use a library: https://www.urlencoder.io/python/

Comment: Thanks will have a look at that library